# mutableStateOf does not update in MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Bluetooth LE scan running which filters for specific Devices. This works fine and I see that the devices get actually added to my list.
But it doesn't trigger anything on my `MainActivity`.
Here is a snipped from the relevant code (it does work similar to a normal scanCallback from BTLE):

```kotlin
@ExperimentalUnsignedTypes
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class BluetoothController(context: Context): ViewModel() {
    private val bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
    private val bluetoothSdk = BluetoothSdk()
    private var lifecycleCoroutineScope: LifecycleCoroutineScope? = null
    private var recentScanJob: Job? = null
    private var binding = BluetoothBinding(context)
    val lockDeviceList: MutableState<MutableList<PSLock>> = mutableStateOf(mutableListOf())

    private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter = if (bluetoothManager.adapter == null) {
        throw Exception("Not supported")
    } else {
        bluetoothManager.adapter as BluetoothAdapter
    }

    val activateBluetooth: Boolean? = try {
        bluetoothAdapter.enable()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        throw Exception(e.message.toString())
    }
    private val psScanListener = object : PSLockScanListener {
        override fun onDeviceScanned(psLock: PSLock) {
            if (fakeWhitelist.contains(psLock.name)) {
                val search = lockDeviceList.value.find { device -> device.name == psLock.name }
                if (search == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "lockCallback: adding $psLock")
                    val list = lockDeviceList.value
                    list.add(psLock)
                    lockDeviceList.value = list
                    Log.d("Bluetooth", "New lockDeviceList: ${lockDeviceList.value}")
                    cancelAllScanning()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onScanError(exception: Exception) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is not the full code but trust me, the scanning works, here is the log:

```
2021-04-15 08:46:24.874 2936-2936/com.veloce.bluetoothadministrationtool D/Bluetooth: New lockDeviceList: [PSLock(name=PSLOCK, macAddress=00:49:69:2F:51, rssi=-76, batteryLevel=1, doorState=-115, lockState=2, openingTimeInSeconds=218, firmwareVersion=111), PSLock(name=Chr_1_3, macAddress=C7:82:AB:F7:AE, rssi=-62, batteryLevel=78, doorState=2, lockState=0, openingTimeInSeconds=4, firmwareVersion=10), PSLock(name=Ruv14_1_1, macAddress=E1:C1:D3:70:43, rssi=-61, batteryLevel=79, doorState=2, lockState=0, openingTimeInSeconds=3, firmwareVersion=10), PSLock(name=Had128_2, macAddress=E6:AE:52:2B:73, rssi=-71, batteryLevel=79, doorState=2, lockState=0, openingTimeInSeconds=4, firmwareVersion=10), PSLock(name=Chr_1_2, macAddress=FD:33:AB:B5:68, rssi=-61, batteryLevel=74, doorState=2, lockState=0, openingTimeInSeconds=4, firmwareVersion=10), PSLock(name=Thu9_1_1, macAddress=ED:F3:F4:DA:E0, rssi=-71, batteryLevel=79, doorState=2, lockState=0, openingTimeInSeconds=3, firmwareVersion=10)]
```

So the data is definitely here, but when I call `bluetooth.lockDeviceList.value` on the `MainActivity`, it does nothing.

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val isOn = bluetooth.activateBluetooth

        if (isOn == true) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Bluetooth is active")
            getLocationPermission()
            bluetooth.startScan()
            Log.d("MainActivity", "PSLock: ${bluetooth.lockDeviceList.value}")
            setContent {
                BluetoothAdministrationToolTheme {
                    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                        Log.d("Bluetooth", "lockDeviceList: ${bluetooth.lockDeviceList.value}")
                        Column() {
                            Text("Hello")
                            Button(onClick = { bluetooth.startScan() }) {
                                Text("Start")
                            }
                            LazyColumn {
                                itemsIndexed(items = bluetooth.lockDeviceList.value) { _, device ->
                                    Log.d("Bluetooth", "YXC: ${bluetooth.availableLocks.value}")
                                    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                                        Card() {
                                            Text(device.name)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            setContent {
                Greeting(name = "bluetooth not turned on")
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to call the `lockDeviceList` on different scopes but it doesn't work anywhere. Does anyone know maybe whats wrong here?

Comment: You don't show the code but I think you're modifying the list that's already created inside the MutableState. This way the state has no idea the list has been modified. Pass a new list instead.

Comment: @m0skit0 ofc it gets modified. Look at the psScanListener: `lockDeviceList.value = list`

Comment: But the list **instance** is the same, there's no way the state knows the list has been modified. Pass a new list instance instead.

Comment: @m0skit0 do I miss your point or what do you mean? It isn' the same instance because `val list = lockDeviceList.value` creates a new list, then adds `list.add(newLock)` and finally assigns the new list `lockDeviceList.value = list` so it is a new instance?

Comment: `val list = lockDeviceList.value`, you're getting the previous list instance, you're not creating a new list. You're getting the previous instance and modifying it.

Comment: Try this: `val list = mutableListOf().apply { addAll(lockDeviceList.value) }`.

Comment: Ahhhh nice, it worked, thank you! Now I understand what you meant. I was a little bit confused because I had a quite similar problem with LiveData before and solved it in the way above. Might you want to write a quick answer below that I can flag it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
val list = lockDeviceList.value
```

you're getting the previous list instance and modifying it, so when setting it back to the state, the state considers no change has been made because the instance is still the same.

If you create a new list instance the state can refresh, for example:

```
val list = mutableListOf().apply { addAll(lockDeviceList.value) }
```

Answer (score -1):

you need use param `MutableState<MutableList<PSLock>>`, not `MutableList<PSLock>` - *`xxx.value`*.

Comment: Yes, it is `val lockDeviceList: MutableState<MutableList<PSLock>> = mutableStateOf(mutableListOf())` or what do you mean?

Comment: If this was the case, it won't compile.